# How to get current element with mousOver React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm new in React, but I have some experience in JS.

My question is:

I have a function and I put this functions to onMouseOver event to element

```
<td> in current situation.
```

I want to get this current dom element and get index of this element next.

My code is bellow:

```js
var Cell = function(k) {


  function getIndex(cell){
   console.log(cell)
  }



  return (
   <td key ={k} onMouseOver={function() {getIndex(this)}}>
    <div className="square__cell" ></div>
   </td>
  )
 
}
```

In js it works something like this. But now in React it returns me null.

If I put in console.log "1" for example it also works. So function is woks and I have only problem to get information about current element

Please help to find out how to do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
You have to bind the function instead of creating new function so the context scope of component remains same

var Cell = function(k) {
        function getIndex(cell){
            console.log(cell)
        }
        return (

            <td key ={k} onMouseOver={this.getIndex.bind(this,k)}}>
                <div className="square__cell" ></div>
            </td>

        )
}
```